# When installing a custom Visual Studio template, do you have to install the interop stuff?

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

I want to install a custom project template with my tool. The template uses a Wizard, so I'm including an assembly and putting it into the GAC on the target machine. Now, this assembly has lots of dependencies like Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll, EnvDTE, and such. Should I redistribute these assemblies, or I can be sure the target machine can find them?

Comment: You can't reasonably pollute the GAC with interop assemblies.  Copy stuff into the Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies subdirectory of the VS install directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not redistribute EnvDTE at least since this would be illegal. Look in the `redist.txt` file under the directory where Visual Studio is installed for a list of microsoft files that you *are* allowed to redistribute. EnvDTE is always available on a machine with Visual Studio installed.

When it comes to Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll I don't exactly know what it is, but I think that youmay be allowed to redistribute automatically generated interops, but probably not the DLL it "wraps". Found a post about this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/0c658855-ee41-4260-9c65-ce048765009e/).

Also worth checking is what the redistributable MSI that comes with the VS SDK contains, since you may redistribute this MSI and install it as part of your program.